# Countdown to 0 on button tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to add a feature like in the TAMAGO application. When you click on a button, the label will change numbers. If it starts on 100, you tap the egg and "100" changes to "99", tap it again and it will change to "98".

My code is:

`-(IBAction)buttonpress:(id)sender {

```
if (button.highlighted) {
    YES;

    label.text = @"999";

    if (button.highlighted) {
        NO;

        label.text = @"998";
    }
}`
```

I tried to repeat this process. But it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is VERY easy to do, almost "Hello World" easy.

Comment: not related to xcode...

Comment: I have just set the label to change when I click the button. But how can I get it to count down every time I tap it?

Comment: can you post the click handler code...it will be easier to figure out what's going on

Comment: `-(IBAction)buttonpress:(id)sender {
    
    
    label.text = @"Button Clicked";

    

}` This is just a simple code, I don't know what I should do now.

Comment: @ep Edit your question to include the code and be sure to format it properly. But before all that, read the [faq] to see why Stackoverflow is not like a forum. Also, take a look at the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to see how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.myTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.myTextLabel.text intValue]-1]
}
```

In this case though the button must have a numeric value when pressed. You could put some further checks in to make sure it is a number if you want. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I don't understand how I can connect the UILabel to the button.

Comment: @eplefrik Sorry, that was for changing the number inside the button. This code will work for changing a UITextLabel's value. Just setup the button to activate this method (IBAction) and set an IBOutlet for the text label (in the above code the text label property would be myTextLabel.)